# What is this language technique called? Example: I don't think we don't love each other

Tags: writing-style, syntactic-analysis, literary-techniques

I don't think that I don't, is this sort of like a double negative? Repetition? Obviously used for emphasis of confusion.

Comment: It's not unlike English.